# Lentidão com group_concat no mysql

Tags: mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, que em algumas partes, quando eu vou exibir os dados para o cliente, estou usando na minha query o group_concat, pois preciso exibir para um item os itens relacionados a ele na mesma linha. Isso funcinou muito bem em quanto tinha poucos registros (2000). Agora que fui fazer um teste de inclusão de muitos registros (200000) dai demora uma eternidade para exibir os dados.
Será que alguém tem alguma ideia do que posso fazer para melhorar isso?

Criei um exemplo do que estou falando

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06bb38/1

Comment: Você pode tirar o plano de execução da sua consulta e postar aqui por favor?

Comment: @JorgeCampos não entendi o que vc quiz dizer, será que o link para o squema em si serve?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html e mais especificamente em: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html

Comment: Imagino que no link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06bb38/1/0 tenha isso que vc pediu.

Comment: Não, não tem. O plano de execução é uma análise que o banco de dados faz na sua consulta indicando quais indices e como o motor está processando os dados. Por exemplo, se você tem um campo NOME na tabela e esse nome não está utilizando um índice significa que em uma consulta com um where no campo NOME haverá um 'full table scan' que significa que o motor irá verificar todos os registros para selecionar apenas aqueles que atende a condição. Olhe essa execução aqui. É isso que você precisa rodar no seu banco. Depois poste o resultado aqui. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06bb38/17

Comment: Pelo que entendi é o que esta no final da página. fora isso não tenho nada. Mas já estou alterando algumas partes desse sistema, para eliminar essa tabela do meio. Valew

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06bb38/18

Comment: Use o comando explain antes do comando select para tu ver, na table aplicacao e na table aspecto sua consulta esta fazendo full scan, e isso sempre irá aumentar o tempo de retorno de consulta conforma a os registros aumentem.

Answer (score 1):

fiz um teste aqui e vi que a consulta esta fazendo select_full_join, ou seja esta dando select na tabela inteira p/ gerar essa consulta, isso que fiz é o tal do plano de execução que o Sr. Jorge Campos esta se referindo.

Possíveis soluções:
   1 - Escreva sua consulta de forma a não fazer o full scan, como? troque esses left join.

```
select 
a.id AS aspecto_id,
a.name,
group_concat(ap.name order by ap.name ASC separator '||') AS aplicacao
from aspecto a, aspecto_aplicacao aa, aplicacao ap
where 
aa.aspecto_id = a.id and
ap.id = aa.aplicacao_id
group by a.id , a.name
order by a.name;
```

só que isso irá buscar resultados íntegros, sem qualquer null, se precisar dos resultados null só da uma mexida ai na consulta.

Possível solução 2:
    Fazer uma stored procedure para essa consulta, isso irá surgir ganho nas consultas em 99,9% dos casos, mas claro, se ficar fazendo o full scan, talvez isso só irá remediar por hora, e irá te custar memória e processamento para continuar com uma boa performance.

Conclusão, sugiro que faça os ajustes necessários na consulta, e se mesmo assim ficar lento, manda p/ procedure assim você estará usando ambas soluções, mas te digo mantenha o foco na forma como escreve as condições, use sempre pk, fk ou índices, e como esta fazendo ordenacao pelo "name" pode fazer um index nesse atributo ai também p/ ganhar em performance. (index type fulltext)

Comment: Entendi o que disse, mas como vc mesmo disse, caso eu precise dos resultados com valores null nesse caso não irá funcionar. Ainda não alterei muito essa parte do que esta, pois ainda precisou de tanto custo do banco, assim que precisar irei ter fazer as devidas alterações, por enquanto estou fazendo outras funcionalidades

Comment: @MarceloDiniz sempre que tu fizeres uma consulta buscando todos os registros da tabela irá demandar tempo relativo ao numeros de registros, por isso te digo melhor pegar somente uma porção/parte fazendo uso dos filtros/condicionando o resultado, e tratar os casos null na aplicação, fica a dica ^^

Comment: @MarceloDiniz a única medida que pode ser feito, se tu quiser manter o full scan é indexar, não é o ideal, mas irá surgir efeito. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/11/23/full-table-scan-vs-full-index-scan-performance/

Comment: Já até fiz isso. Foi o mais rápido a ser feito e como vc disse, não é o ideal, mas pelo menos é algo.